# How to make outer pane scroll instead of inner one

Tags: richtextfx

Firstly, as you probably noticed in tags, I use RichTextFX. CodeArea is just its text area with some features.

I have `ScrollPane` with inner elements:

```
ScrollPane
|   AnchorPane
|   |   VBox
|   |   |   HBox
|   |   |   |   Label
|   |   |   |   CodeArea
|   |   |   HBox
|   |   |   |   Label
|   |   |   |   CodeArea
|   |   |   HBox
|   |   |   |   Label
|   |   |   |   CodeArea
...........................
```

When I'm trying to scroll while my cursor isn't hovering `CodeArea`, `ScrollPane` scrolling like it should do.

But if my cursor is on `CodeArea`, as I assume, it trying to scroll the `CodeArea`, even if there is nothing to scroll (content fits well).

`ScrollEvent` isn't being called on `ScrollPane`, `AnchorPane` nor `CodeArea`, but `VBox`.

I tried to bind properties like `scrollPane.onScrollProperty().bind(vBox.onScrollProperty())` or `scrollPane.onScrollProperty().bind(codeArea.onScrollProperty())` and many others but that didn't work.

This question doesn't affect classic `TextArea`.

**How to make `ScrollPane` scroll instead of `CodeArea` when hovering `CodeArea`?**

You can also use this example to reproduce the problem:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.CodeArea;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        scrollPane.setContent(vBox);
        CodeArea codeArea = new CodeArea();
        codeArea.setPrefHeight(2000);
        Label label = new Label("Can you scroll here while hovering code area?");
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(codeArea, label);
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            codeArea.appendText("Sample text\n");
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 400, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: What is CodeArea?

Comment: @kleopatra sure. Added one to the question.

Comment: @jewelsea RichTextFX's thing. Located [here](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/blob/master/richtextfx/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/richtext/CodeArea.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example do:

```
codeArea.addEventFilter( ScrollEvent.ANY, scroll -> 
{
    vBox.fireEvent( scroll );
    scroll.consume();
});
```

Comment: don't refire an event from an eventHandler - that's breaking the dispatch sequence contract (starts a complete capture/bubble phase)